# Complex Angular Material Table Cells

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Is there a way to reference `*matCellDef` values from within other DOM objects within that specific cell? (If its even possible to have `div` tags and such there)

Take that code snippet as example:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">{{ item.id }}</mat-cell>
```

Lets say that within this cell I want a small red dot next to the ID if the id is odd and no dot if its even.
How would i solve that?

One of my ideas was:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let item; item.id % 2 ? odd=true : odd=false">
    {{ item.id }} <div *ngIf="odd">redDotDiv</div>
</mat-cell>
```

or to move the `*matCellDef` check into the `<mat-cell>` tags (between `{{ }}` ) themselves.

But now I'm here, so that obviously did not work. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matCellDef is for defining the row variable.
What you should do is checking the condition inside ngIf:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
    {{ item.id }} <div *ngIf="item.id % 2 == 0">redDotDiv</div>
</mat-cell>
```

Comment: That's what I tried, but the variable was not defined. (At least I think I did, will retry as soon as I'm back)

Answer (score 0):

Working example :)

html

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}}
        <div *ngIf="element.position % 2 == 0" class="redDot"></div>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
```

css

```
.redDot{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

ts

```
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position'];
  dataSource = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```